# Angular: Class with Array of Foreign Keys

Tags: angular, typescript, in-memory-database, angular-tour-of-heroes

I've built the class "meal" with two properties like in the tour of heroes tutorial from angular:

```
export class Meal {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Now I want to declare a class like "Mealplan". Each Mealplan should contain five Objects of Meal, like:

```
export class Mealplan {
  weekId: number;
  mealPlan: Meal[] = new Array(5)
}
```

Important is, that I want to add existing Meals to the Mealplan. I do not want to create new Objects of Meal. Is it more recommended to just refer to the Meal ID in Mealplan? For example:

```
  createDb() {
    const meal = [
      {
        id: 101,
        name: 'Tatar',
        price: 18.00,
        description: "Sojasauce / Chili / Crème fraîche / Tobiko"
      };
```

and

```
const mealPlan = [
 {
  id: 1,
  mealPlan: [101, 101, 101, 101, 101]
 }
]
```

Is this the best way I can handle this problem? Or would it be better to use a Map or List or something else?

Answer (score 2):

You could associate a type to mealPlan like this:

```
export class Mealplan {
  weekId: number;
  mealPlan: [Meal, Meal, Meal, Meal, Meal];
}
```

Now, doing this would be **invalid**:

```
let plan = new MealPlan();
plan.mealPlan = [new Meal(),new Meal(),new Meal(),new Meal()];
```

whereas this is **valid**:

```
let plan = new MealPlan();
plan.mealPlan = [new Meal(),new Meal(),new Meal(),new Meal(), new Meal()];
```

Comment: hey there. thanks for your comment, but I dont think I should create new objects inside a mealplan. I have edited my opening post, do you have another idea?

Comment: I have created a little example for you https://stackblitz.com/edit/json-pipe-example-4vbixg

Comment: thanks for your effort! I understand your point, and I think it's a great solution. However, I need to figure out how I do it with the in-memory-db. PS: I'm from hamburg too! :D @storm85049